# Find line that starts with something, and in this line find word

Tags: javascript, regex

i would like to know if is possible to first find a line that starts with some specific word, than in this line, search for other world.

I have this regex http://www.regexr.com/3bsl1

**String**

```
Empregados/Avulsos 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
Contribuintes Individuais 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
RAT 34.792,90 0,00 0,00 0,00 34.792,90
RAT - Agentes Nocivos 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
Valores Pagos a Cooperativas 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
Adicional Cooperativas 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
Comercialização Produção 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
Evento Desportivo/Patrocínio 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00 0,00
COMP 07 Empregados/Avulsos INSCRIÇÃO bla ble bli 082 sk3$ ^# x sms
COMP 0 283 20 3882 03
```

**Regex**

```
/^COMP\s*?(Empregados/Avulsos)/
```

So the goals here is to find the line that starts with COMP, which is working, than immediately jump to Empregados/Avulsos, but is not working this part.

Thanks.

Comment: _"than immediately jump to Empregados/Avulsos"_ What is expected result ? Forward slash at `(Empregados/Avulsos)` not appear escaped ?

Comment: Um.... `^COMP\s.*(Empregados/Avulsos)` is that what you are asking for??

Answer (score 2):

Test this:

```
/^COMP.*?(Empregados\/Avulsos)/gm
```

Working example: http://www.regexr.com/3bsla

Note: Always escape special characters like `/.[]` etc.

Comment: Thanks @Marcos Casagrande

Comment: The `?` is not necessary, but I like that you don't have a group, capturing or otherwise, for the `COMP` bit.

Comment: Yeah i know it is not necessary but still, I don't like to be greedy :P

Answer (score 2):

If you use a [*non-capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html), you can match the starting part of the line, "COMP", and then just capture the bit you want, which is the `Empregados/Avulsos` part.

The regex looks like this:

```
/(?:^COMP.*)(Empregados/Avulsos)/gm
```

That way, the only match, `$1` equals "Empregados/Avulsos".

[Try it out on Regexr](http://regexr.com/3bsl7)

Comment: @Mariano Yep, I realised that after I saw Marcos' answer, and even commented on his answer as such.